# how connect fragments and tabs from sliding menu in android studio?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am creating an app for a local business and I'm having a hard time having the tabs in the menu go to the information XML layouts.

I'm wondering how you supposed to connect your fragments to work with the nav tabs?

Thanks for any help!

here is my Main Activity.

```
package com.armyofpunk.kincardinetheatreguild;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu; 
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
    implements NavigationDrawerCallbacks {

/**
 * Fragment managing the behaviors, interactions and presentation of      the navigation drawer.
 */
private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;
private Toolbar mToolbar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_actionbar);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

    mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
            getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_drawer);

    // Set up the drawer.
    mNavigationDrawerFragment.setup(R.id.fragment_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer), mToolbar);
}


@Override
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {

    Fragment fragment;
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager(); // For AppCompat use getSupportFragmentManager
    switch(position) {
        default:
        case 0:
            fragment = new AboutUs_fragment();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new PlayBill_fragment();
            break;
    }
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, fragment)
            .commit();
}
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    //Toast.makeText(this, "Menu item selected -> " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen())
        mNavigationDrawerFragment.closeDrawer();
    else
        super.onBackPressed();
}

//public void about(View view) {
   // Intent intent = new Intent(this,com.armyofpunk.kincardinetheatreguild.About.class);
    //startActivity(intent);
```

//  }

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {
        // Only show items in the action bar relevant to this screen
        // if the drawer is not showing. Otherwise, let the drawer
        // decide what to show in the action bar.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a ViewPager with PagerTitleStrip. Here is a detailed tutorial on how to do this:

[Creating Swipe Views with Tabs](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html)